# Android: How to integrate AppleTV/Airplay for streaming with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, streaming, airplay, apple-tv

I have an application for android which is streaming music over the internet. Now I was thinking about integrate streaming with `AppleTV` and `Airplay` (and maybe via `Bluetooh`). But if I search in google (guess my search skills suck nowadays), I only find a lot of Apps which offer that functionality, but no tutorial, framework which give me a good start point.

**Question:** Do you know any good pages/tutorial?

Thanks in advance!